# Detect NeoPixel status

Tags: microcontroller

I am powering a 1m strip of [these](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1376) with a Spark Core (which is like a small web-enabled Arduino if you're not familiar with it). Right now everything is working swimmingly on my workbench, but I'm looking forward to when it is in the field, and I want to know if there's any way for the controller to detect the status of the strip? In particular, I would love to know if the strip is connected and working and ideally how many pixels are present. I'm expecting the answer to be no, but I'm no electrical engineer and maybe there's some magic I'm not aware of.

Also, what's a good primer on things I should be protecting against (the EE version of defensive programming, I guess)? The circuit is just the Spark Core, the NeoPixels, a protective resistor and a capacitor as described here (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/best-practices). Currently it's powered by USB, but will eventually be powered by an adapter connected to mains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea: The pixels pass the data through, removing one message, each time.
You could write to the string as though it has one more pixel.
Connect the data line from the far end back to the Arduino, and check that you get one message out the other end. This would confirm that the string is working.

Note that the first line on the Adafruit site says "There are some things to watch for. These LED's use about 9.5 Watts max (~2 Amps @ 5V) per meter"  So you will quickly run into trouble powering them from USB. You will need to protect your circuit against the neopixel strip!

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll play around when I get home. As far as the power issue, in the final product the power and ground on the strip will be isolated from the microcrontroller and data circuit, and it will be powered by a 5v wall wart.

Comment: @TBridges42 good idea to separate the power supplies. By the way you get amazing [12V to 5V buck converters](http://power.murata.com/en/products/dc-dc-converters/single-output-non-isolated/okr-t-6-w12-c.html), many amps, small packages. If you're going to run the strip any distance from the wall wart, consider using 12 V and dropping down to 5 V at the strip.

Comment: Ok, I think this will be a little awkward because I'll have to run a data wire back the whole length of the strip (or use a second microcontroller at the other end), but I also think it'll work so I'm going to accept it as an answer.

Comment: You could just toggle the last LED Bright/Off/Bright/Off and look for the variations in current (or even just the supply voltage droop). If the signal makes it all the way, then all of the pixels are probably working.

Comment: The problem with that is it requires visual inspection. I like the first idea because I can detect issues remotely from the web service that controls the thing.

Comment: @TBridges42 I was thinking of having the micro observe the current or voltage. Not difficult to sample the 5V rail at the start of the strip, just one more wire back to the micro, and it'll probably droop a bit even with one light on.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was wondering about. Would the voltage drop be enough to positively identify the difference? Is the output from a 5V DC converter stable enough that an LED activating can be reliably distinguished from variations in the mains supply?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work. But what I would do is not try to categorically state that 5.00 V is off, 4.98 V is on. Rather switch the last LED on and off many times, and record the on-off difference. This will eliminate slow-changing background effects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23710/discussion-between-tomnexus-and-tbridges42).